# Is this expected behavior of Template Haskell?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, haskell-lens

Can anyone tell why this code doesn't compile

```
data A = A {
  _b  :: B
}
makeLenses ''A

type B = String
```

with message

```
Not in scope: type constructor or class B
```

and this does:

```
type B = String

data A = A {
  _b  :: B
}
makeLenses ''A
```

Without `makeLenses` everything compiles fine.

Why can't I have type synonim declaration after makeLenses?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only the definitions before the template haskell call are accessible in the scope.

See this previous question on the same topic: [Haskell: Template Haskell and the scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20876147/haskell-template-haskell-and-the-scope).